# How do I save the git-diff from a makefile

Tags: git, makefile

I have a project that I compile using a makefile. I want to save the output of `git diff` into the executable when it is compiled. Simply assigning the output of `git diff` to a variable in the makefile, and then passing to the compiler e.g.

```
GIT_DIFF := $(shell git diff)

CXXFLAGS += -D$(GIT_DIFF)
```

fails because the parts of the string gets evaluated, for example newlines split the compile command into several non-sensical commands.

What is the best way to pass in the output of `git diff` at compile-time into a string I can use in C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. Not too sure how robust or portable it is though. This solution assumes the shell is bash. In the makefile I have

```
GIT_DIFF := $(shell printf '%q\n' "$$(git diff | awk '{ gsub("\"","\\\"",$$$$1) ; print $$$$1 }' ORS='\\n')" )

CXXFLAGS += -DGIT_DIFF=\"$(GIT_DIFF)\"
```

and then in a header file I have

```
// Convert macro to a string constant
#define STRINGIFY1(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY1(x)

constexpr auto git_diff = STRINGIFY(GIT_DIFF)
```

(this is a C++11 project).

Unpacking that command a bit:

- `$$` escapes the `$` symbol in the makefile, so that bash sees the command

  ```
  printf '%q\n' "$(git diff | awk '{ gsub("\"","\\\"",$$1) ; print $$1 }' ORS='\\n')"
  ```

  (I learned this here https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/k3kjqxtppx-escape-dollar-sign-on-makefiles)
- in the `awk` command the `gsub()` bit escapes quote marks, because otherwise the C++ compiler (maybe also bash) would get confused. (from here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/awk-find-and-replace-fields-values/)
- the `ORS='\\n'` bit of the `awk` command replaces newlines with `\\n` so that they don't get interpreted as line endings by `printf` (credit to this blog post https://timmurphy.org/2014/02/12/replacing-newline-characters-in-linux/)
- The `printf '%q\n'` bit uses the bash builtin `printf` to escape all special characters (this is the bit I know of that may be less portable, needs checking if you want to use a different shell). (Copied from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141323)

The string that's passed to the C++ code is full of escape sequences, so is not very readable. It can be converted back to something more readable by reversing the `awk` substition and using `echo -e` to evaluate the escaped characters (for some reason this needs to be done twice). So if the string is saved into a text file, say `mygitdiff`, then

```
echo -e $(echo -e "$(cat mygitdiff | awk '{ gsub("\\\"", "\"",$$1) ; print $$1 }' IRS='\\n')")
```

should make it something readable.

This method is awkward, and the string that's passed to the C++ isn't very readable, so if anyone has a better solution, or suggestions for improvements, that would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a Python script that's called from the makefile to write the git diff into a header file. The solution I came up with has some error handling. It is C++11-specific because it uses a 'raw string literal' to avoid needing to escape special characters (also uses `constexpr auto`, but that could be replaced with `const std::string`). This one saves a hash from `git describe` as well as the diff.

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from string import ascii_uppercase

try:
    from git import Repo
except ImportError:
    # print a return code to stdout so we can capture and test it in the makefile
    print(11)
    raise

scriptdir = Path(__file__).parent

repo = Repo(scriptdir.parent)

diff = repo.git.diff()

# Find a string to use for the delimiter
delimiter = "_DIFF_DELIMITER_"
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    if ")" + delimiter not in diff:
        delimiter_success = True
        break
    delimiter = "_DIFF_DELIMITER_" + letter + "_"
if ")" + delimiter in diff:
    # print a return code to stdout so we can capture and test it in the makefile
    print(12)
    raise ValueError(
        "save_git_version.py failed to find a delimiter that is not in the git diff"
    )

with open("my_git_version.hxx", "w") as f:
    f.write("constexpr auto my_git_hash = \"")
    f.write(repo.git.describe(abbrev=40, dirty=True, always=True, tags=True))
    f.write("\";\n")
    f.write("constexpr auto my_git_diff = R\"" + delimiter + "(")
    f.write(diff)
    f.write(")" + delimiter + "\";\n")

# print a return code to stdout so we can capture and test it in the makefile
print(0)
```

and in the makefile:

```
save_git_version_status := $(shell ./save_git_version.py)
ifeq ($(save_git_version_status), 11)
  $(error "gitpython not installed. You can install with 'conda install gitpython' or 'pip install --user gitpython'")
endif
ifeq ($(save_git_version_status), 12)
  $(error "save_git_version.py failed to find a delimiter that is not in the git diff")
endif
ifneq ($(save_git_version_status), 0)
  $(error "save_git_version.py failed with an unrecognised error $(save_git_version_status)")
endif
```

Then you can `#include "my_git_version.hxx" in the C++ file where you want the` my_git_hash`or`my_git_diff` strings.